# How many CuratorFramework must be created within a large scale project?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

We're creating large-scale projects.
spring-boot project which uses curator to interact with zk servers, how many CuratorFramework instance should we create?
What level of work can a CuratorFramework instance deal with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted on Curator's website - http://curator.apache.org/curator-framework/index.html - "CuratorFramework instances are fully thread-safe. You should share one CuratorFramework per ZooKeeper cluster in your application."

Comment: Good job. Thank you : )